# Why Merriweather Sans duplicate l in flying point?

Tags: archlinux, truetype

When I type "Col·laborador" I get exactly this with other letter types:
[image]

but with Merryweather Sans, I get "Coll·laborador":
[image]

I use [ttf-merriweather-sans 1.006-3](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ttf-merriweather-sans/) in ArchLinux

Comment: In [google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Merriweather+Sans) if you type "Col·laborador" it's ok. So it seems a arch specific problem. "l·l" is ["gemminated l"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpunct#Catalan)

Comment: It depends on what font rendering engine you are using. Probably it's freetype on linux.

Comment: @el.pescado How can I know that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in that font's OpenType definition.

Its author included a `locl` OpenType feature for the language code `CAT` (Catalan) that was supposed to replace the combination `/l' /cdot' /l` with `/ldot`. The `'` characters after the first two names indicate what characters are to be replaced by the new one (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/opentype/afdko/topic_feature_file_syntax.html#5.e). However, the author made a mistake there:

```
replace /periodcentered after /l before /l with /ldot
```

and so it replaces *just the dot character* with `ŀ`. That means that you get this

[image: InDesign, original text, "Catalan" set as language]

with an OpenType-aware program such as Adobe InDesign (and only with the applied language set to "Catalan"). Note the double `l`, as in your own findings.

The output from another program confirms this; characters that *do not take part* of a replacement are in gray, replaced characters are in black.

[image: partial output OpenType feature list]

*Both* `/l`s are in gray, only the center dot is black. A correct definition should have shown the left hand `l` and `L` in black as well.

The font you link to is version 1.006; an older Merriweather Sans that I found (1.003) does not contain this particular OpenType feature and so does not display this error.

To fix it, adjust the OpenType code and regenerate it from its source, or contact its author. Contact details are on the [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Merriweather+Sans?selection.family=Merriweather+Sans) page for this font. (I have left a message in there, referring to this question.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, @usr2564301. It's an amazing work. So it is a bug, as I suspected.

Comment: @somenxavier: I've filed it as a bug, so keep an eye out for an improved version.

Comment: is there a reference of this bug (URL of the bug tracking system)? If there is, can you share it with us?

Comment: @somenxavier: no, I just filled in the Feedback form on the Google fonts site. I can check a typographer's forum we both visit, perhaps I can give him a heads up if it takes more than a week or so.

Comment: Wow, that's awesome answer!

Comment: @usr2564301 it seems the bug is not corrected in latest version https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ttf-merriweather-sans/